# Анимация рамки вокруг элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: *введите сюда описание изображения*]
Как отрисовать такую анимацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вариантик. Сейчас сразу срабатывает анимация, но можно на `hover` сделать если что.

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.left::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: height .4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.left::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 0;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: width .4s .4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: height .4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 0;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: width .4s .4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes height {
 from { height: 0; }
 to { height: 100%; }
}

@keyframes width {
 from { width: 0; }
 to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="title">Мир uriage</div>
  <div class="line left"></div>
  <div class="line right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что бы анимация начиналась при скроле, то есть когда елемент видно. Нужно js'ом как-то, да?

Comment: @Roman viewportChecker библиотекой воспользуйтесь. Когда элемент видно (доскроливаете к нему) добавляет к нему класс какой-либо. а в этом классе код анимации вставьте! (это как домашнее задание) я ухожу сейчас просто!

Comment: Да спасибо, сделал через добавление класса)